# Is there any formula to calculate the number of normal subgroups of $S_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

> Is there any formula to calculate the number of normal subgroups of
>   $S_n$?

Suppose i have an answer to this question it is easy to answer how many homomorphism is there from $S_n$ to any other group. Because each normal subgroup defines a kernel for a homomorphism...

Comment: An answer to this question does not make it easy to calculate the number of homomorphisms from $S_n$ to another group because the kernel doesn't uniquely determine the homomorphism (think, for example, of the case where the kernel is trivial).

Comment: mm... but removing the trivial.. we will get something know..@QiaochuYuan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$S_n$ has exactly $2$ normal subgroups for $n = 2$, $4$ normal subgroups for $n = 4$, and $3$ normal subgroups for every other $n$ - these are $1$, $S_n$, and $A_n$.

For $n \le 4$ this can be done by hand (note that the Sylow $2$-subgroup of $A_4$ is normal in $A_4$, hence characteristic in $A_4$, hence normal in $S_4$), and for $n \ge 5$ this follows from simplicity of $A_n$ (if $H \unlhd S_n$, $H \not \supseteq A_n$, then $H \cap A_n \unlhd A_n \implies H \cap A_n = 1 \implies |H| = [H : H \cap A_n] = [HA_n : A_n] = [S_n : A_n] = 2$, but a subgroup of order $2$ is normal iff it is contained in the center, and $Z(S_n) = 1$).

Comment: @bof: Yes, thank you for pointing that out - I was excluding $S_1$ (which is the trivial group) from the list (for no particular reason)